# Is reputation requirement for commenting from the start or was it introduced later?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges, stack-exchange-history

I have looked at some post regarding this but nobody seem to have given its answer. For example this post [Has the Comment system always required a minimum reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131695/has-the-comment-system-always-required-a-minimum-reputation)
talks about this question among some others but nobody seemed to responded to it. So I request the Stack Exchange community to help us out with it.

Comment: Well, dunno if from the start, but surely it was in place 6 years ago back in [October 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101012040337/http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 4):

In the very beginning, the only way to "comment" was to post an answer (which anyone can do); the `@Username` became a link to another answer on the page:

> [image: 1]

animuson♦, in the answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328036/6083675) explains:

> This is a *very, very* old feature before commenting existed and answers were actually used to communicate with other users. The links use a hashtag identifier to link to the answer on the same page, like so:
>
> ```
> <a href="#44667">Troels Arvin</a>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly believe the requirement of 50 reputation points to post a comment was there from the very beginning of Stack Overflow, when it emerged from its [private beta phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191791/regarding-the-beta-badge-on-stack-overflow).

As Jeff mentions in [Podcast #43](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/podcast-43/), which was posted back in February 2009 when SO was still new:

> Joel asks about the rationale behind requiring 50 reputation to leave a comment, but allowing a brand new user to post a question or leave an answer

Comment: It can't have applied from the start since there were only one-reputation users... Or there were no comments back then ;)

Comment: @Pat there was a [private beta phase](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191791/regarding-the-beta-badge-on-stack-overflow), where users posted stuff, and gained reputation. :-)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Comments didn't exist at the start.  Jeff mentioned one of the big blunders of the initial build was that there were no comments, and so the things that people did to get around that were more disruptive than the comment feature he wanted to avoid having.  Of course, it didn't take long for them to get added.

Comment: @Servy didn't he mean before the initial migration from his blog?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't remember, and I wasn't around at the time to know from experience.

Comment: @Servy well, I asked someone who took active part in the private beta of SO, let's see if he replies. :)

Comment: IIRC correctly, comments were not added until after Stack Overflow was public. Jeff deliberately avoided them for as long as he could, because he wanted to avoid allowing SO to be used as a forum or social network. I do know the 50 rep requirement has been there from the moment comments were first introduced, for the same reason... to encourage newbies to treat it as a Q&A site rather than a forum or social network. But this was **a very long time ago**. SO it 8 years old now, and I may not remember this correctly.

Comment: It looks like I probably do remember wrong. The data explorer shows the first comment on August 1, 2008. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/582020/first-comments That's definitely private beta territory.

Comment: @Joel thanks, looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql#comment15092952_129) is the first comment then... but anyway, if you say the 50 rep requirement was there from the beginning, it confirms my answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - No, you're remembering it correctly. That comment first started as an answer and was converted to a comment by a moderator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/130/19679 . We went back and converted a number of those in response to flags. I think comments came in late September of 2008, and there was a period where people couldn't comment.

Comment: @Brad good to know, maybe it's worth a separate answer here then?

Comment: @ShadowWizard but from stack exchange data dump I found some users who did only commenting which is not possible until unless there was time period when reputation restriction was not there.